# open any file chosen after specific time

Tags: c#, winforms

I want my program to open the selected file which selected by filedialo1  after specified time any answer please

this is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            string Chosen_File = " ";
        }
        public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Chosen_File = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            Process.Start(Chosen_File);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

the erroer is The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: We are not coding and emailing answers here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the answer emailed to you, you can tick the box below your question.

The problem you have is that you're not saving the filename.

I would also have the timer initially disabled, to prevent it trying to open a file if the user cancels the dialog box. Also, don't forget to disable the timer in its `tick` event handler, otherwise the file will be opened multiple times.

```
string Chosen_File = null;

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Chosen_File =  MyDialog.FileName;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```